# Can I process sessions server-side in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, rdbms

Can I set some global session-wide variables and have them automatically applied to queries and stored procedures in MySQL?

Or I should always explicitly send any parameters in queries?

**UPDATE**

Theoretically it could be possible, but practically I am starting to think that is not.

1) It could be possible to use session variables in views. Then it would be possible to `SET` such variable on connection open and then have customized views output.

But unfortunately it is impossible to use variables in views. It is possible to use variables in stored procedures. So

2) It is possible to use session variables in stored procedures. Then it would be to get filtered results from SP.

Unfortunately, MySQL doesn't allow to use stored procedures as tables, i.e. it is impossible to query SP without temp table.

Comment: automatically applied HOW? just because a variable exists doesn't mean it'll magically get thrown into a query, unless you explicitly list it.

Comment: Sure. Manifest them in a control table.

Comment: @MarcB I am not opposing to LIST it; if you know how to go with listing, then pls answer

Comment: Even if it did work once I wouldn't think of doing this. I am risk-adverse. Why bank your strategy on something fragile at best.